# How do I make shutil.move perform a direct move instead of copying file then deleting the original?

Tags: python, shutil

I have a huge OSMC/kodi media collection and am trying to organize it better.  I am using shutil.move to move the files from a drop folder to the proper storage location after the script makes sure that the files (video, nfo file, artwork) are named properly, and that the right files are all there.  A couple of the backup drives (which I want organized the same way) are full (less than 5 Gb left).

I wanted to use shutil.move because that looks like the easiest way to *move* a folder from the drop folder to the right folder per the organizational scheme - I can handle the folder and its contents and structure as a single object.  Even though the source and destination folders are on the same partition of the same drive, shutil is copying the folder and all contents to the destination and then deleting the original.  Since a move on the same partition is usually just an update to the file allocation table, why is shutil doing a copy-and-delete instead of just updating the file allocation table?  Is there a way to force it to not copy?  Many of the movies are bigger than the 5 Gb or so left on the drive, and there isn't a season of any show that's less than 5 Gb combined.  This makes the move fail because the drive runs out of space.

I know I can use other methods/modules, but would like to be able to treat the folder and its contents as a single unit, instead of going through every single step and every single file for the move.

Comment: shutil.move() internally tries `os.rename()` before it falls back to copying by reading and writing. What happens if you call `os.rename()` directly? Does it give an error? Which error?

Comment: BTW, I would suggest editing the title. It makes it sound like you want the file copied.

Comment: This question isn't answerable until you provide the information requested by Nick above. Accordingly, I'm voting to close it as lacking a [mre].

Comment: Crazy week and this had to be a low priority for me.  Using os.rename(), no error, and the speed at which it was moved makes it look like it was an actual move (update to file pointers in file allocation table), not copy to new location and then delete the original.  I tried it with one movie folder.  Will be testing with a TV series, which is the most complex move/rename.

Comment: os.rename() solves the problem.  I ran it on a folder containing multiple TV series, and it works beautifully.  It simply updates the table of contents instead of copy then delete the original - which is exactly what I wanted the script to do.  Seeing this, I have to question your statement that shutil.move() tries os.rename().  If this were the case, I shouldn't have had to try os.rename(), so wouldn't have found a different end result.